# Connection Speed using HTTP Request

Tags: http, tcp, webserver

We are making an application involving a server(tomcat, apache, linux) and multiple mobile clients(Android, iPhone, Windows, Nokia J2ME).

Normally the clients and the server will communicate using http.

I would like to know the download and upload speeds of the client from the http request that it made.

Ideally I would not like to upload a file and download a file to come up with these speeds. I am assuming that there might be some thing at the HTTP protocol level that can give me this, or some lower layer of the network.

Answer (score 2):

If only it were that simple.

Even where the bandwidth [and latency](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/know-your-enemy-latency/) of a network are very well defined, the actual throughput will be limited by the congestion window and where the end points are in establishing the slow start threshold. These can affect throughput by a factor of 20 or more.

There's nothing in HTTP which will provide metrics for these. Some TCP stacks will expose limited information about throughput (as used by [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/), [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/techinfo.html)).

However if you really want to gather useful metrics on HTTP throughput, then you need to start shoving data across the network - have a look at [yahoo boomerang](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang) for an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If the http connection goes to the Apache server first, you can use Apache Bench to do all sorts of load testing.  It comes with apache and can be invoked with something like the following.

Suppose we want to see how fast Yahoo can handle 100 requests, with a maximum of 10 requests running concurrently:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.yahoo.com/
```

Comment: If I am not getting it wrong, apache bench will need to run on my clients, but in affect I want to calculate the speed staying on the server. To add to this it will be a hassle to put in all this info on each of the clients.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP does not deal with connection speeds. Although I could imagine some solution that involves some HTTP (reverse) proxy that estimates speeds on a connection and sets custom headers to pass this info. You would also need to to associate stats of different connections with particular client. I have not seen yet a readily available solution for this.

Also note that

1. network traffic can be buffered or shaped so download speed may depend on amount of data transferred or previous load of network. So even downloading file would not be accurate.
2. Amount of data transferred depends on protocol level (payload wrapped in HTTP wrapped in gzip wrapped in TLS wrapped TCP). Which one do you want to measure? Or what do you want to achieve with this measured speed?

Comment: This is an app suite for a telco company. So what we would do is that if the speed is slow we will recommend them to move to a different cell/site (location) for a better speed.

Comment: If this concerns with user experience then maybe just measure response times? Say if your application has some requests that are sent via JavaScript then I think it is possible to measure how long they actually take (e.g. by using some wrapper around calls that could transparently gather statistics). And then use this data as measure for responsiveness. This way this could be implemented completely on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some Real User Monitoring (RUM) tools that can do this passively (they get a feed from a SPAN port or network TAP infront of the servers at the data centre)

There are probably ways of integrating the data they produce into your applications but I'm not sure it would be easy or perhaps given the way latency and bandwidth can 'dynamically' change on a mobile network that accurate.

I guess the real thing to focus on is the design of the app, how much data is travelling across the network, how you can minimise it etc.

Other thing to consider is whether you could offer a solution that allows some of the application to be hosted in the telco's POPs (some telcos route all their towers back to a central pop, others have multiple POPs)